# Web form calendar.selecteddate To sql Date column format

Tags: c#, sql, date

I'm trying to take a 'calendar.selecteddate' from a web form calendar, and pass that date to my sql database date data-type column.

If I select the 5th of January 2014 the entry works fine (2014/05/01). If I select 13th January there is an exception while sending the data to the database. It's converting the date to a yyyy/mm/dd format. Is there a way to change either my sql database data type format - or, a nice bit of code that'll convert it before I pass it to the database?

```
SqlHandler.SqlQuery(String.Format("INSERT INTO Sessions VALUES ('{0}', '0')"
                      , Calendar.SelectedDate.ToString()));
```

thanks as always

Comment: Is this C#?  It might help you if you put a tag on it saying so.  You might then get some help from people who know C#.

Comment: Apologies, this is C#

Comment: Don't pass it as a string - pass it as a `DateTime` type.  You can do this if you use a Parameterized query, which you should be doing anyways (or you run the risk of SQL Injection).  That way, you won't have any conversion issues; like for your working example, what did it actually insert: The 5th of January... or the 1st of May?